# FIrebase firestore - How should I replace a whole collection daily?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating website where I gather data and store them in Firestore.
However, the data needs to be updated every day and so I need to delete old data every day.

So currently, I get all the new data and store them in Firestore. Then query for all the data in the collection that was created before today and delete them one by one.
The bad part of this is, if I go to the site while the deletion is going on, I could theoretically get some old data that is being deleted.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [transaction or batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to make all the changes atomically, so that there is no inconsistency between queries.

You could also write all the new data to a different collection, then only after that succeeds, delete the documents in the original collection.  You would need another document somewhere that the client queries first to tell it which collection is the newest, compete collection to use.

To be sure, any solution you choose will have edge cases that make it problematic.  The best you can do is choose a solution that's "least bad" for your particular case.